# Android FFMPEG - Low FPS & File Size is massive

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

I am new to Android app development and I have been asked to make a video splitter app. I am trying to use FFMPEG, but the library size is massive and makes the .APK file 140MB. How can I solve this? Similar apps are around 15MBs in size.

Also, the framerate starts at ~30FPS and drops to around 2.2FPS over time when trying to split a 30 second long video into two parts. How can I solve this? This is my code currently:

```
package splicer.com.splicer;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler;
import com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpeg;
import com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.LoadBinaryResponseHandler;
import com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.exceptions.FFmpegNotSupportedException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button;
    private TextView textView;
    private FFmpeg ffmpeg;

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        try {
            ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onStart() {}

                @Override
                public void onFailure() {}

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {}

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {}
            });
        } catch(FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setY(200);
        textView.setHeight(700);
        textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openGallery();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * A native method that is implemented by the 'native-lib' native library,
     * which is packaged with this application.
     */
    public native String stringFromJNI();

    public void openGallery() {
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String [] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
        }

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String [] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
        }

        Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(gallery, 100);
    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 100) {
            MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            try {
                retriever.setDataSource(getBaseContext(), intent.getData());
                String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
                long splitCount = Long.valueOf(time) / 1000 / 15;
                if(splitCount > 1) {
                    final String path = getRealPathFromURI(getBaseContext(), Uri.parse(intent.getData().toString()));

                    for(int a = 0, start = 0; a < splitCount; ++a, start += 15) {
                        // I am only testing with .mp4s atm, this will change before production
                        final String targetPath = path.replace(".mp4", "_" + (a + 1) + ".mp4");

                        ffmpeg.execute(new String [] {
                                "-r",
                                "1",
                                "-i",
                                path,
                                "-ss",
                                String.valueOf(start),
                                "-t",
                                String.valueOf(start + 15),
                                "-r",
                                "24",
                                targetPath
                        }, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
                            @Override
                            public void onStart() {}

                            @Override
                            public void onProgress(String message) {
                                textView.setText("onProcess: " + message);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(String message) {
                                textView.setText("onFailure: " + message + " --- " + path);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(String message) {
                                textView.setText("onSuccess:" + message);
                                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getBaseContext(),
                                new String [] { targetPath }, null,
                                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {}
                                });
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFinish() {}
                        });
                    }
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                retriever.release();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't believe everything here is as optimal as it could be, but I'm just trying to prove the concept at the moment. Any help in the right direction would be amazing, thank you!

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Comment: There are two layers of complexity here: your code and the actual `ffmpeg` command being executed. Since the issues may not lie in your code, but with your `ffmpeg` command, you should show the actual command being executed and the resulting log from that command.